# Show seven day calendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

I want a calendar with only 7 days visible.
The days `['Ma', 'Di', 'Woe', 'Do', 'Vrij', 'Za', 'Zo']`
must stay in the same position. Only the numbers may change.

My JS code doesn't work.

```html
<div class="calendar">
   <p class="month" id="month"></p>
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-around" id="daysContainer">
                        
     </div>
</div>
```

```
function generateWeekDays() {
    var daysOfWeek    = ['Ma', 'Di', 'Woe', 'Do', 'Vrij', 'Za', 'Zo']; 
    var today         = new Date();
    var currentDay    = today.getDay();
    var daysContainer = document.getElementById('daysContainer');
    
    daysContainer.innerHTML = '';
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var dayIndex   = (currentDay + i) % 7;
        var dayName    = daysOfWeek[dayIndex];
        var dayNumber  = today.getDate() + i;
        var dayElement = document.createElement('div'); 

        var classes = 'flex-direction-row ' + dayName.toLowerCase(); 
        if (i === 0) classes += ' active'; 
        dayElement.className = classes;

        dayElement.innerHTML = '<div class="number">' + dayNumber + '</div>' 
                             + '<div class="day">' + dayName + '</div>';

        daysContainer.appendChild(dayElement);
    }

    var monthElement         = document.getElementById('month');
    var monthNames           = ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Augustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'];
    var currentMonth         = today.getMonth();
    monthElement.textContent = monthNames[currentMonth];
}

window.onload = generateWeekDays;
```

If I use `console.log` then I see nothing in my console..
I don't know what I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```js
const
  daysOfWeek    = 'Ma-Di-Woe-Do-Vrij-Za-Zo'.split('-')
, monthNames    = ('Januari-Februari-Maart-April-Mei-Juni-Juli-Augustus'
                  +'-September-Oktober-November-December').split('-')
, daysContainer = document.querySelector('#calendar > div')
, monthElement  = document.querySelector('#calendar > p')
  ;
generateWeekDays();

function generateWeekDays()
  {
  let
    dateOn  = new Date() 
  , c_Day   = dateOn.getDate()
  , cWkDay  = dateOn.getDay()
  , c_Month = dateOn.getMonth()
  , c_Year  = dateOn.getFullYear()
    ;
  
  monthElement.textContent = `${monthNames[c_Month]} - ${c_Year}`;
  
  // set date on first week day 'Ma'
  dateOn.setDate(dateOn.getDate() - (( cWkDay +6 ) %7 ));
 
  // clear daysContainer
  while( daysContainer.firstChild ) 
    { daysContainer.removeChild(daysContainer.lastChild); }

  for( let dayName of daysOfWeek )
    {
    let
      dayNum = ((dateOn.getMonth()) === c_Month) ? dateOn.getDate() : '-'
    , dayCls = (dayNum ===  c_Day) ? ' class="active"': ''
      ;
    dateOn.setDate(dateOn.getDate() +1 ); // prepa 4 next day

    fragHTML = new Range().createContextualFragment(` 
      <div>
        <div>${dayName}</div>
        <div${dayCls}>${dayNum}</div>
      </div>`);
      
    daysContainer.append(fragHTML);
    }
  }
```

```css
#calendar  {
  min-width : 24em;
  max-width : 24em;
  }
#calendar > p {
  font-weight    : bold;
  letter-spacing : .2ic;
  padding-left   : 1em;
  }
#calendar > div {
  display         : flex;
  flex-direction  : row;
  justify-content : space-around;
  }
#calendar > div > div {
  background-color : lightblue;
  text-align       : center;
  width            : 3rem;
  } 
#calendar > div > div > div {
  padding    : .4em 0 .2em 0;
  } 
#calendar > div > div > div:first-of-type {
  font-style    : oblique;
  border-bottom : 1px black solid;
  }
.active {
  background-color: hotpink;
  }
```

```html
<div id="calendar">
  <p> Month & year values </p>
  <div> names of days with their calendar values (flex elements) </div>
</div>
```